# When using Alt + tab to change windows vba code got error

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet with floating menu, on the menu has button, when click on the button it will move to that range. But when I using 2 file and change by using Alt + Tab, it has debug when I click on the button And when I use the same file but open with new window to view other sheet
I'm using excel 2016

```
Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()
Sheets("Adjusted FS").Range("A237").Select 'Debug is here
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = ActiveCell.Row
End Sub
```

Comment: With this question, it may be helpful to include which version of Excel you are using. The behavior may be different between Excel 2007 (which uses MDI) and Excel 2013+ (which uses SDI)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `.Select` when the sheet is not active. So activate it first:

```
Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()
  Sheets("Adjusted FS").Activate
  Sheets("Adjusted FS").Range("A237").Select
  ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = ActiveCell.Row
End Sub
```

<sub>Note: Depending on the reason why you are selecting it in the first place, this may not be necessary, but this is how to bypass the error.</sub>

Comment: I'm staying at sheet "Adjusted FS" of workbook No.1. Then I Alt Tab to Workbook No.2, roll the mouse to see data, then I Alt Tab back workbook No.1 to the file has that code and click to the button to move to Range("A237") so it's still error

Comment: could you help me to fix it, please.